# Meaning of "matched by" in the given text

Tags: meaning-in-context

Please help me figure out the meaning of "match by" in the following sentence:

"When, after 1850, governments began to rid cities of
some of their worst slums, many working class men and women discovered that urban ‘improvement’ meant relocation into dreary ‘model’ tenements, whose amenities were **matched by** their barrack like anonymity; or
removal from one dilapidated structure to another in the wake of a clearance scheme—the nineteenth century called it ‘ventilation’—that replaced
ancient, overcrowded housing with a more sanitary—and for the landlord,
more profitable—railway switching yard."

For more context, please visit the following link:

https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Pcf1nrvUwD0C&pg=PA57&dq=were+matched+by+their+barrack+life&hl=hi&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM35L_7bvWAhXEsY8KHfGfBAUQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=were%20matched%20by%20their%20barrack%20life&f=false

Answer (score 2):

**matched by — equal to — as bad as**

Residents were moved from homes in an area which had "life and soul" to invented accomodation, where there was nothing for them. Every aspect of the new life was equally bad.

Comment: Thanks. 

In the given sentence, where did you find the words that mean "life and soul"?

Comment: In the antithesis of "barrack like anonymity".

Comment: The words  "barrack like anonymity" are related to "dreary model tenements". In my view, they cannot be considered the antithesis of "barrack like anonymity".

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "matched by" in your quote is being used to imply **similarity**.

Similarity has two aspects:

1. **resemblance**: the anonymity was stark and plain ("barrack-like"), just like the amenities.
2. **correspondence**: the anonymity (lacking individuality) and the state of the amenities were both related to an obvious lack of concern for any aesthetic (the tenements were "dreary").